# Add to cart query string keeps going to product page

Tags: addtocart, querystring

I'm using magento 1.9.1 and on a custom listing page I'm trying to add an add to basket form. This is supposed to add to the basket using a query string.

```
<?php $formKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();?>
<form action="/shop/checkout/cart/add?product=4149&qty=1&super_attribute[136]=147?super_attribute[240]=1636" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $formKey; ?>" />

<input type="submit" value="Add to basket" />
</form>
```

I've tried a few variations on how the url is formatted and I will look at Un-hardcoding it once ,i have got a working format.

But for now it just keeps directing to the product page and asking me to select options.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153691/magento-add-a-product-to-the-cart-via-query-string-without-form-key-parameter), [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring) and [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Internet_Marketing/E-Commerce/Q_28527117.html) about formatting a query string for this. I'm certain that I've done this on older versions of magento in the past with the format given in the code above.

FYI -

```
I need to add it as a config product and set the options rather than add the simple directly.
```

All help welcome.

Comment: are your want direct url query or form??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @amitbera answer would work so I upvoted it but I had this working before I saw his so I'll post it also.

```
<?php
    $url = '/shop/checkout/cart/add?product='.$_product->getId().'&qty=1';
    $productAttributeOptions = $_config->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_config);
    foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {
        $url .= '&super_attribute['.$productAttribute['attribute_id'].']='.$_originalProduct->getData($productAttribute['attribute_code']);
    }

    if($_originalProduct->getData('is_in_stock')):
    $formKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();

?>
    <form action="<?php echo $url; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $formKey; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="in_cart" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Re-order this shoe" />
    </form>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I you use form then
It will  good idea to use

1. Dynamic cart url using function `$this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product)` in form action
2. use the super attribute as input field.

> ```
> <?php $formKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();?>
>     <form action="<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product) ?>" method="post">
>     <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="super_attribute[136]" />
>     <input type="hidden" name="super_attribute[136]" value="147" />
>     <input type="hidden" name="super_attribute[240]" value="11636" />
>     <input type="hidden" name="qty" value="1" />
>     <input type="submit" value="Add to basket" />
>     </form>
> ```